# What algorithm does PGP use to encrypt the private key using the passphrase?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp, private-key

The PGPKeyRingGenerator constructor takes in a passphrase to encrypt the private key. What is the algorithm that it uses to do this? It has a field called encAlgorithm, but I couldn't find any documentation explaining what these algorithms are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, PGP uses IDEA ([Refer this](http://www.quadibloc.com/crypto/co040302.htm)).

The other algorithms can be defined in  encAlgorithm and following are supported by OpenPGP,

```
public interface SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags
{
    public static final int NULL = 0;        // Plaintext or unencrypted data
    public static final int IDEA = 1;        // IDEA [IDEA]
    public static final int TRIPLE_DES = 2;  // Triple-DES (DES-EDE, as per spec -168 bit key derived from 192)
    public static final int CAST5 = 3;       // CAST5 (128 bit key, as per RFC 2144)
    public static final int BLOWFISH = 4;    // Blowfish (128 bit key, 16 rounds) [BLOWFISH]
    public static final int SAFER = 5;       // SAFER-SK128 (13 rounds) [SAFER]
    public static final int DES = 6;         // Reserved for DES/SK
    public static final int AES_128 = 7;     // Reserved for AES with 128-bit key
    public static final int AES_192 = 8;     // Reserved for AES with 192-bit key
    public static final int AES_256 = 9;     // Reserved for AES with 256-bit key
    public static final int TWOFISH = 10;    // Reserved for Twofish
}
```

They all use CFB mode with no padding.

Comment: FYI: the corporate version of PGP uses AES256.

Comment: There's no such thing as "by default". PGP Desktop software uses AES nowadays, other software has different defaults, at the same time letting you specify desired algorithm. Moreover, IDEA is a patented algorithm and so it's strongly not recommended for use.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on PGP software, for example GPG uses CAST5 by default.

Answer (score 0):

> PGP encryption uses a serial combination of hashing, data compression, symmetric-key cryptography, and, finally, public-key cryptography; each step uses one of several supported algorithms. Each public key is bound to a user name and/or an e-mail address. The first version of this system was generally known as a web of trust to contrast with the X.509 system which uses a hierarchical approach based on certificate authority  and which was added to PGP implementations later. Current versions of PGP encryption include both options through an automated key management server.

Taken from [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).
It should be what you are looking for.